# Regular expression to match letters and digits, where some symbols can appear between them

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to match letters and digits, where `.`,`-` and `_` can appear between them.

1. Examples of valid matches: "stephan", "mike03", "s.johnson", "st_steward", "john-johnson", "12345", "324_231351231".
2. Examples of invalid users: ''--123", ".....", "john_-", "_steve", ".info".

I came up with this expression

`[A-Za-z0-9.\-_]+`

but it will also match things like `stefan_johnson_` which should not be matched because `_` can only appear between the letters and the digits. The same holds if we have `_` or any of the other already mentioned symbols in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[._-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wbmJiK/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - one or more ASCII letters or digits
- `(?:[._-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `[._-]` - a `.`, `_` or `-`
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - one or more ASCII letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.

It may turn out you need to support any Unicode letters or digits, then use

```cs
^[\p{L}\p{N}]+(?:[._-][\p{L}\p{N}]+)*$
```

where `\p{L}` matches any Unicode (base) letter and `\p{N}` matches any Unicode digit.

Replace `$` with `\z` if you do not want to allow a trailing `\n` (line feed) char.

Also, see my ["*Validating strings with comma-separated values (with no leading/trailing separators)*" YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XU-ode0Mwek) explaining this kind of validation technique.

Comment: Thank you for such for the detailed response! I'll need some time to look at your answer, but I really appreciate it. I'm a student and I'm really glad that there're people like you who are willing to help! Thank you! Appreciate you!

Comment: May I ask you something I've just came up with? I think the idea is supposed to be very similar with the one you used in your expression. I am trying to write a regex where I have at least two words, separated by dots. Each word is sequence of letters and can have hyphens between the letters, e.g. `gmail.com`, `gmail-staff.eu`, `yahoo.fr`, `admin-gmail.com`, `mail.facebook.com`. I think `[A-Za-z]+(?:\-[A-Za-z]+)*` matches a single word (observing the rules). How can we make it to match more words, separated by dots?

Comment: @Medi `[A-Za-z]+(?:[-.][A-Za-z]+)+` or `[A-Za-z]+(?:[-.][A-Za-z]+)*`